# convert MeijerG to form Standard Functions in Mathematica

Tags: special-functions, conversion

I'd like to convert

```
MeijerG[{{}, {1., 1.}}, {{0., 0., 4.}, {}}, -1. T λ]
```

to its Standard Functions (For example Bessel function or ...). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation on [`MeijerG`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeijerG.html),

> > Use `FunctionExpand` to expand `MeijerG` into simpler functions:

```
FunctionExpand@
 MeijerG[{{}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 4}, {}}, -T λ]

(* -11 + 11 E^(T λ) + 6 EulerGamma - 
 5 E^(T λ) T λ + E^(T λ) T^2 λ^2 + 
 6 (11/6 - EulerGamma - Log[-T λ]) + 6 Log[-T λ] + 
 6 (-ExpIntegralEi[T λ] - Log[-T λ] + 
    1/2 (-Log[1/(T λ)] + Log[T λ])) *)
```

Note this doesn't work if you use floats instead of integers,

```
FunctionExpand@
 MeijerG[{{}, {1., 1.}}, {{0., 0., 4.}, {}}, -1.0 T λ]
(* MeijerG[{{}, {1., 1.}}, {{0., 0., 4.}, {}}, -1. T λ] *)
```

Comment: For a simpler form use `MeijerG[{{}, {1., 1.}}, {{0., 0., 4.}, {}}, -1. T \[Lambda]] // 
   Rationalize // FunctionExpand // FullSimplify`

Comment: Why would you introduce rationalize and Fullsimplify to the expression ?